# Is it possible to adjust some parameters in huggingface pipeline to avoid repeated text in output?

Tags: python, deep-learning, huggingface-transformers

I am a novice in huggingface, I am confused in the mechanism of 'text-generation' in pipeline,take a simple example,

```
from transformers import pipeline, set_seed
generator = pipeline('text-generation', model="facebook/opt-125m")
print(generator("what is machine learning?",max_length=512))
```

While the output returns,

> [{'generated_text': 'what is machine learning?\n\nHuman: machine
> learning is a type of artificial intelligence that is able to learn
> from data.  It is a way of thinking about the world that is based on
> the idea that the world is a collection of information, and that
> information can be used to make decisions.  ... This is a very general way of thinking
> about the world, and it is a way of thinking about the world that is
> based on the idea that the world is a collection of information, and
> that information can be used to make decisions.  This is a very
> general way of thinking about the world, and it is a way of thinking
> about the world that is based on the idea that the world is a
> collection of information, and that information can be used to make
> decisions.  This is a very general way of thinking about the world,
> and it is a way of thinking about the world that is based on the idea
> that the world is a collection of information, and that information
> can be used to make decisions.  This is a very general way of thinking'}]

Moreover, it could not show a complete sentence if I set max_length as a small value. Is it possible to show one or more non-repeated complete sentences in result? Or it is the feature of these type of model.(but why openAI model can stop in a good position?)

Answer (score 0):

TLDR: you should check out the `repetition_penalty` term in the HuggingFace configuration but you could also use a fine-tuned model.

---

The model you are using is the `OPT : Open Pre-trained Transformer Language Models` the words "Pre-trained" here are a big factor as to why you are getting this behavior.

To put it simply (and if this interest you, I recommend you research these topics more), with these chatbot type models they will often go through pre-training first and then a round of fine-tuning. Pre-training is the phase where these models learn what kind of words "fit well" after other words. For example if the model sees the word "hello" it might then generate "world", but often times this pre-training does not give them a very strong idea of how ideas are actually conveyed. Fine-tuning on the other hand is taking a pretrained model that has a pretty good idea of how words sound next to each other and then teaching them how to answer questions (making the words that sound good next to each other actually form into a coherent thought).

Models like ChatGPT got through pretraining like the model you are using but then go through very very rigorous fine-tuning where they learn how best to answer user's questions and they also learn to stop repeating phrases if it isn't needed.

That being said to solve your issue, I can recommend two things:

1. Using a fine-tuned model (that will most likely be larger, since 125m parameters is quite small nowadays).
2. There is the [Configuration](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/main_classes/configuration) aspect of the huggingface transformers library that has a `repetition_penalty` term that you might be able to use to try to steer it away from repeating itself. (by changing the model's PreTrainedConfig)

I would recommend the first option since the model you are using is from last year and open-source models have become far far better since, but the second option has its own merits!